# Redux toolkit accessing state from thunk

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-toolkit

I'd like to get a value stored in state in a thunk, in this case `projectId`. Can I access this value without passing it as a parameter when the action is called?.

```
interface RepoDetailsState {
      openIssuesCount: number
      error: string | null
    }

const initialState: RepoDetailsState = {
  openIssuesCount: -1,
  error: null,
  projectId: 'someProjectId'

}

const repoDetails = createSlice({
  name: 'repoDetails',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
  // ... reducers ...
  }
})

export const {
  getRepoDetailsSuccess,
  getRepoDetailsFailed
} = repoDetails.actions

export default repoDetails.reducer

export const fetchIssuesCount = (
  org: string,
  repo: string
): AppThunk => async dispatch => {
 //How do I access projectId from state?
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access your state via the `getState` parameter.

```
export const fetchIssuesCount = (
  org: string,
  repo: string
): AppThunk => async (dispatch, getState) => {
// Do something with state
 getState()
}
```

It can also be seen [here](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk#motivation). (Ctrl + F getState to see more examples)